# Update image in RAMPlayer

Tags: maxscript

I can put two images into RAMPlayer;

```
(
    file1 = "C:\\rendered\\moose.jpg"
    file2 = "C:\\rendered\\squirrel.jpg"
    RAMPlayer file1 file2   
)
```

but I don't know how to reference the open RAMPlayer window and pass in a (newly updated/rendered) image back into it.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on research through the SDK, and through the MaxScript code (the majority of which is provided as an SDK sample), it appears this is not possible at present.  It would require an SDK and/or MaxScript extension.  My suggestion is to visit the official "Small Annoying Things" forum for 3ds max, and place a vote on the request to replace the RAM Player.  There is already a request logged here:
http://3dsmaxfeedback.autodesk.com/forums/80695-general-feature-requests/suggestions/1159811-update-or-re-architect-ram-player

Note that 3ds max allows multiple RAM Player windows.  For the functionality you're requesting, it is necessary to specify which window to affect, so the function to launch the RAM Player needs to return a key or ID value for that purpose.

With creative hacking, it is possible to obtain a window handle to the RAM Player window you're interested in, and then send low-level window messages via MaxScript.  In this way, you could either close the window, to relaunch it with new files of interest, or, you could press the two "Open Last Rendered Image" buttons.  I can research the details if those are avenues you're interested in.